# Notification JavaScript function is not working online

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications

i tried to use this function

```js
  function notifyMe(nofTitle,nofbody,nofLink) {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification(nofTitle, {
      icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
      body: nofbody,
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open(nofLink);
    };

  }

}
notifyMe("ab","ab","ab");
```

Its work in localhost but not working online

Comment: Define "not working".  How does it fail?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, what happens?  Is there an error on the console?  When you debug, where does it fail?

Comment: I mean the "box" notification appears when you execute the code on the localhost ,But does not appear permanently when you work it online

Comment: The problem was resolved only on the security site which starts with the HTTPS protocol and I was working on the site with its insecure image via the HTTP protocol, anyway I did not know this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved only on the security site which starts with the HTTPS protocol and I was working on the site with its insecure image via the HTTP protocol, anyway I did not know this information –